# Finding the second highest salary SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Input: Salary: 200, 300, 100 with respected id 1, 2, 3
Output: 200 [Here 200 is the closest value of the 300]
```

I have tried in this way:

```
 select 
 Case
 When (salary < (select max(salary) from Employee)) 
 then salary
 Else
 NULL
 end as SecondHighestSalary
 from Employee
 where salary < (select max(salary) from Employee)
 order by salary desc limit 1;
```

After running this query it returns the output as expected for some conditions. Like if input is salary: 100 with the respected id 1 then my query returns only empty value But it should return the null value.
If you can complete the query or suggest how to complete then you are most welcome.

Comment: Just select all, order descending by salary and limit to 2 – if the maximum contained yet disturbs use that as subquery and select minimum from...

Comment: If salaries values are 300,300,200,100 then what value is 2nd - 300 or 200? And what is your MySQL version?

Comment: Ok I will give a try @Aconcagua

Comment: It should be 200 @Akina

Answer (score 2):

You could use this query this way.

> SELECT salary FROM Employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1

This query will fetch second most big salary.
This would work!

Comment: It worked as expected

Answer (score 2):

General solution:

```sql
SELECT salary
FROM employee
WHERE salary < ( SELECT MAX(salary)
                 FROM employee )
ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1
```

Solution appicable to MySQL 8+:

```sql
WITH
cte AS (
    SELECT salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) drnk
    FROM employee
)
SELECT DISTINCT salary
FROM cte
WHERE drnk = 2
```

Comment: It worked as expected

Answer (score -1):

`select salary from Employee order by salary desc limit 1 offset 1;`

This should retrieve the second highest salary. It orders the salaries in descinding order, then neglect the first result by `offset 1`, then `limit 1` limits the result to one record.

Comment: Do not post code only also add an explanations